# Force a UITextField to be un-editable like UITextView's 'editable' property

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I want a UITextField which can't be edited, but which the user can place the cursor in. That means that when the cursor is in the UITextField, you can view the text in the UITextField, but you can't modify its contents, like UITextView's **editable** property. I can't use UITextView for various reasons, so please help me.

```
tacticNameView = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 161, 23)];
tacticNameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tacticNameView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
tacticNameView.enabled = NO;
```

The 'enabled' property didn't solve my problem, so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this Delegate method**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {  
    return NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this delegate method.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       return NO;
}
```

or you can remove the interaction for the textfield using

```
textfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```